# Wait for javascript to show an element to hide it afterwards

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, live

Hi I have a JQuery js that does something like this after AJAX call:

```
$element.next().after('<td><b>OPTION SAVED</b></td>');
$element.next().next().hide();
$element.next().next().show('slide', {direction : 'left'}, 1000);
```

Now what I want to do is call this =>

```
$element.next().next().next().hide("slow");
```

So basically I want to create an element dynamically, slide it from the left and after it has appeared, I want it to hide it slowly again. How do I do this? My problem is that js code is executed even while the element has not yet completed the sliding (or its creation maybe?) so When I call hide("slow") it tells me I called it on undefined and nothing happens...

Thanks

Comment: you would need to use a callback on completion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$element.next().after('<td><b>OPTION SAVED</b></td>').hide().show('slide', {direction : 'left'}, 1000, function(){$(this).hide();});
```

Should work, the chaining of the calls means the after will return the element you just added then you show it and add a callback function to hide it again.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a callback function :

```
$element.show(duration, easing, callback_function);
```

Callback function will be executed once animation is complete.

Bye !

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your description of the problem.  Your issue is that you have one too many `next`s.

```
$element.next().next().show('slide', {direction : 'left'}, 1000);
```

Note that there are 2 `next`s here.

```
$element.next().next().next().hide("slow");
```

Then here are 3 `next`s.  **NOT** the same element.  If you want to hide the same element then drop a `next` off of the `hide`.

Or even better, just chain it:

```
$element.next().next()
   .show('slide', {direction : 'left'}, 1000)
   .hide("slow");
```